# Estimate significance of double difference in means

Tags: r, mean, causality

this may be a trivial question.

In my data, I have two groups `grp1` and `grp2`. In each group, I have some observations assigned to the treatment group and some observations assigned to the control group.

My question is whether there is a statistically significant difference on `dv` of the treatment in `grp1` and `grp2`. In some way, this is a difference in differences.
I want to estimate if the following difference is significant:

dd = mean(dv_grp1_treat-dv_grp1_control)-mean(dv_grp2_treat-dv_grp2_control)

```
# create data
install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(librarian,tidyverse,truncnorm)
aud_tr<- as.data.frame(list(avglist=rtruncnorm(625, a=0,b=4, mean=2.1, sd=1))) %>% mutate(group="grp1_tr")
aud_notr <- as.data.frame(list(avglist=rtruncnorm(625, a=0,b=4, mean=2, sd=1))) %>% mutate(group="grp1_notr")
noaud_tr<- as.data.frame(list(avglist=rtruncnorm(625, a=0,b=4, mean=2.4, sd=1))) %>% mutate(group="grp2_tr")
noaud_notr<- as.data.frame(list(avglist=rtruncnorm(625, a=0,b=4, mean=2.1, sd=1))) %>% mutate(group="grp2_notr")
df<- bind_rows(aud_tr,aud_notr,noaud_tr,noaud_notr)
unique(df$group)
[1] "grp1_treat"   "grp1_control" "grp2_treat"   "grp2_control"
```

I know how to run t.test for difference in means between in each group, but how do I do it if I want to examine the difference across groups?

```
t.test(df$dv[df$group=="grp1_treat"],df$dv[df$group=="grp1_control"])
t.test(df$dv[df$group=="grp2_treat"],df$dv[df$group=="grp2_control"])
```

Comment: Maybe this tutorial is suitable for your situation: https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.536444!/file/MASH_2way_ANOVA_in_R.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a two-way analysis of variance (ANOVA). Firstly, you should ensure that you separate out "group membership" and "treatment versus control" into two columns, since these are really two distinct variables:

```r
df$treatment <- ifelse(grepl('treat', df$group), 'treat', 'control')
df$group     <- ifelse(grepl('1', df$group), 'grp1', 'grp2')
```

Then you can carry out a two way ANOVA using `aov`

```r
summary(aov(dv ~ group + treatment, data = df))
#>              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> group         1   1.18   1.175   1.362    0.245    
#> treatment     1  26.14  26.145  30.307 1.14e-07 ***
#> Residuals   197 169.95   0.863                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This tells you that, in this sample, the effect of treatment was significant, but the effect of group membership was not

---

**Data**

Obviously, we don't have your data since it wasn't supplied in the question, but the following sample data frame has the same names and structure as your own:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(dv = c(rnorm(50, 3.2), rnorm(50, 3.8), 
                        rnorm(50, 3.5), rnorm(50, 4.1)),
                 group = rep(c('grp1_control', 'grp1_treat', 
                               'grp2_control', 'grp2_treat'), each = 50))
```

Comment: Dear Allan, thanks for your quick and helpful reply. Just to clarify: the aov, tells me that the treatment effect was significant. My question is whether treatment had a significantly different effect between te two groups. are these the same? Also, I do provide code to generate the data but your example works well anyways

Comment: @Alex no, you need an interaction effect to say whether the effect of treatment was different between the two groups. Try `summary(aov(dv ~ group * treatment, data = df))`